# Register IPV4 public address in one region and use it in another

Tags: dns, ipv4, whois

I wanted to understand the result I get from the whois service "whois " command on Linux and if the country I get back can be guaranteed to be the country where the IP is bound to a server?

Would it be possible to register a Public IPV4 IP address with [ARIN](https://www.arin.net/about/welcome/region/#regional-internet-registry-regions) in the USA, but attach it to a server running in Europe or would the top-level RIR country register always route traffic to where the IP is registered?

I am unable to find a definitive answer to this from my googling.

Answer (score -1):

> guaranteed to be the country where the IP is bound to a server?

Absolutely not.

Your question is directly answered right from ARIN website at https://www.arin.net/resources/guide/request/

> Out of Region Use
>
> ARIN registered resources may be used outside the ARIN service region for
> organizations with a real and substantial connection with the ARIN region.

The detailed explanation can be read at https://www.arin.net/participate/policy/nrpm/#9-out-of-region-use.